# User access control dialog box with python executable

Tags: uac, python-3.3

I have multiple python scripts which I have converted to executables using py2exe. When I run them I get a UAC dialog box saying

> 'Do you want the following program from an unknown publisher to be able to make changes to your computer.'

I'm running windows 7, 64bit, python 3.3.

In order to be sure it wasn't due to my code, I copied the following simple script from the web and created an exe. Still the same problem.

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

def get_appdata_directory():
    CSIDL_APPDATA = 0x001a

    dll = ctypes.windll.shell32
    app_data_directory = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(wintypes.MAX_PATH)

    found = dll.SHGetFolderPathW(0, CSIDL_APPDATA, 0, 0, app_data_directory)

    return app_data_directory.value

appdata = get_appdata_directory()
```

The script merely finds the path to the appdata directory.

What needs to be done in order to avoid the UAC dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an *"Assembly Manifest"* for your application. It has to declare `requestedExecutionLevel=asInvoker`, and then either

- embed it as a resource (`RT_MANIFEST`)
- or have it in the same folder as your exe, and named `MyApp.exe.manifest`